# jquery datepicker onclose event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have added jQuery 1.11 in footer with jquery ui 1.11. Also added ui css at header. Now datepicker events are not working

```
$('.datepicker_default').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            alert('working');
            //$(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd-mm-yy');
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker_default" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="datepicker">
```

Here is head section and footer
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a6ed80380612e5cfb82

Comment: you get error in console?

Comment: @guradio No error. There are error but with other plugin. Even tried after removing those plugin still not working

Comment: @OP, It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8w8v9/945/ May be you are facing version related issues..

Comment: My UI not working. No style there. Doesn't know why

Comment: Ok.. show us how you have added reference to those `scripts` and `css` files..

Comment: OMG... There are loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooot of scripts..  Ok.. so which `datepicker` you are referring here? `bootstrap` or `jquery-ui`

Comment: please see question.  I have edited

Comment: jquery UI @Guruprasad Rao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is a conflic between bootstrap-datepicker and jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'); ?>"></script>
```

bootstrap-datepicker and jquery-ui-datepicker have the same

$( "#div" ).datepicker();

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/